# Ubuntu 14.04 Server does not boot right after initial installation

Tags: boot

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 Server on a PC where I had 12.04 installed and running smoothly.

However, right after the main message that comes after the installation, it does not boot to the main welcome screen, but freezes instead.

What could be the problem and how to recover from it? I have removed all additional H/W from the Server thinking maybe drivers might be causing boot to freeze.  So far nothing.

Your assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is trying to switch to a high resolution video mode for the console and your hardware isn't cooperating.

#### Fixing this while at the machine

When Grub2 shows up:

- Highlight the menu item for Ubuntu and press <kbd>e</kbd>
- Go to the line where it loads the kernel and press <kbd>End</kbd> to go to the end of the line
- Add `nomodeset`
- Press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> to boot

With any luck it will boot into the login screen. This won't save that option but at least now you can edit the file for Grub2 and update it to save that option if it works.

#### Fixing this for good

- Log in (ssh will probably do, if you know the machine's IP)
- Update the grub config file:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/default/grub
  ```
- Find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
- Edit the line to include `nomodeset`. In my case, the line looked like this afterwards:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset"
  ```

  but you may also have other parameters such as `quiet` and `splash`, which don't need to be removed.
- Save/exit nano
- Run

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Reboot